# curl or wget command to verify a host is serving HTTPS on port 443?

Tags: curl, wget

I'm not married to either tool, I'm just hoping to find the fastest way to verify that all hosts in a list I pipe to either curl or wget are listening for HTTPS traffic on 443 rather than some other protocol that's set to 443 as a listener. I've got an egress filtering product that's about to drop support for that edge-case and would like to make any impacted teams aware.

I'm not particularly concerned if the host certificate is *valid*, as that's a problem for the app teams to talk with that vendor about or otherwise handle in their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider hosts as FQDNs in a file as,

```
$ cat list.txt
hotmail.com
google.com
cloudflare.com
127.0.0.1
```

Running this command on Linux,

`cat list.txt | xargs -I{} bash -c "curl -m3 -k https://{}:443/ 1> /dev/null 2>&1 && echo {},yes || echo {},no"`

Produces the output as,

```
hotmail.com,yes
google.com,yes
cloudflare.com,yes
127.0.0.1,no
```

The `-m3` option to `curl` sets the maximum time spent before it would give up, and `-k` ignores certificate validity. This command seems to reliably fail when `https` is not negotiated on the hardcoded port `443`.

Note that depending on the openssl version your edition of curl was compiled against, it may not have support for TLS 1.1 and lower and will report a failed connection in cases where the host did not support at least TLS 1.2. Which, I suspect, for the purposes of your test, is as good as non-HTTPS.

It's sad to hear that an egress filtering product is dropping support for detecting the protocol and falling back on layer 3 constructs. In case you are looking for an alternative on AWS or GCP, I work for Chaser and we make one that goes well beyond just testing for modern TLS levels. Checks for spoofed headers, etc. as well. See [DiscrimiNAT](https://chasersystems.com/).